# Interpreting Results of Multivariable Regression / how to transform variables to improve results

Tags: machine-learning, r, regression, linear-regression

I am working on a project that predicts the Market Cap (value) of different crypto-currencies. My data is very small (51 observations) and I initially have 18 X-variables. I was hoping to get feedback on my modeling approach and results, and suggestions on improving the model (particularly by transforming variables / with a non-linear regression) technique. I will do my best to keep the post clear and brief, and hope it can be helpful to others working on a similar analysis. The post may seem long, but a lot of it is images. Also, I am doing this in R, and can share any code on request.

1.) My first action was to **log-transform the Market Cap** (Y-variable) into log(Market Cap). Here are 2 graphs, of Market Cap and of log(Market Cap) of my 50 observations:
[image: here we go]

...the outlier point, with a $190B market cap, is bitcoin, and the model badly overfit to this data point if I did not log-transform. For this reason, I think this first action of log-transforming the Market Cap is a good action.

2.) 12 of the 50 observations were missing values for 6 of the X-variables. Rather than throwing these observations away, **I predict missing values** for these 6 X-variables by fitting, for each of these 6 X-variables, a simple linear regression between the (a) the X-variable with missing values, and (b) one of the remaining 12 X-variables with no missing values. For (b), I chose the X-variable with the highest pearson correlation to the missing-value-X-variable. I use this simple linear regression to predict missing values.

3.) I then fit an initial linear model with all 18 variables. However, since 18 variables will almost certainly overfit to 50 data points, and because there is some multicollinearity to the X-variables, I then use **stepwise regression with backward elimination** to fit a model with fewer variables. The R summary output of the model returned using backward elimination, with 9 variables, is here:

[image]

and the R diagnostics plots from this model are:

[image]

4.) Lastly, here is a grid with variable distributions and correlations for these 9 predictor variables + the log(Market Cap):

[image]

as well as a table of **Variance Inflation Factors**

[image]

My thoughts on next steps are to fix the remaining multicollinearity issue by removing additional variables, and also remove some outlier data points indicated in the Residuals vs. Leverage graph. I also plan to test the model on a test data-set (I did a 40 / 10 split), 5 times using 5-fold cross validation.

I am interested in anyone's thoughts on transforming the X-variables, which I currently do none of. The grid of histograms / correlations / scatter plots shows that many variables are right-skewed. Additionally, I have graphed the simple linear regression fit between log(Market Cap) and each of the 9 remaining variables, and received these plots (for 4 of the 9):

[image]

And noticed for the most part that none of the X-variables seem to have a great linear-fit with log(Market Cap).

Any thoughts on next-steps on my model building would be **greatly, greatly appreicated.** Apologies again for the long post, but I felt that thorough / lots of images / plots would be helpful here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your VIF values are extreme, and your residuals plot is a right-opening megaphone (vice a null plot, which is what you want). It looks like the residual plot is being strongly affected by BTC.

If I were working this I would look into Principal Component Analysis (PCA) for two reasons:

1) It can help mitigate your multicollinearity and drive down your VIFs

2) It can reduce the number of predictor variables you're using (linear regression is better on fewer variables)

I would also consider removing the BTC data point *just to see what happens*. This can give you some insights that can help you build the model. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Given,

1. You have a very small training sample which does not let you test on a hold out to a large extent
2. You are looking to do some feature selection
3. You are looking to reduce multi-collinearity

This could be a good use case for LASSO. It would help with removal of multi-collinearity in your models along with assisting in feature selection. You could try a 5-fold cross validation on the complete sample. As the model performs coefficient shrinkage, it should also generalize better on hold-out samples in case your other models seem to be over-fitting.